# Construction of a Poisson process of random intensity

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have just started to use the wolfram mathematica language as part of my thesis. I am looking to build the following quantities:

(i) I try to represent the counting function of a Poisson process of intensity a random constant of gamma law, that is, for all $t$, $\lambda_t = \Theta$ with $\Theta$ having a gamma law

(ii) in a second step, I try to plot graphically the quantity $N_t / t$ in which the quantity $N_t$ designates the counting function of the Poisson process

**For the first part:**

I wrote the following code:

```
v:= RandomReal[Gamma[1,2], 1];
td1 = RandomFunction[InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[v, t], {0,20}];
ListStepPlot[{td1, td1}, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

However, it does not work ... Would you have any idea to correct this problem?

**For the second part:**

What is the syntax for building the count function as a function of time?

I thank you in advance for any track in the reflection.

Alexandre

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange! I took the freedom to add some markup to your post.

Comment: You just have to add `v:= First@RandomReal[Gamma[1,2], 1];` because your function `v` should return a number not a list. Is the output graph what you want?

Comment: thank you very much ! It works very well. On the other hand, I would like at the output a graph providing a certain number of realizations of the counting function to see the effect of the parameter Theta. I gave a name to my previously calculated random process. I thought to make a list with this name several times so that the random intensity is updated every time. Nevertheless this does not seem to work. Is there a way to do that, without having to manually build multiple achievements and overlay them?
Alexandre

Comment: what I would like is to superimpose on the same graph many realizations of a Poisson process whose intensity is a random variable that one draws following a law of the gamma type.

What I did before:
I fixed an omega scenario. Then I pulled a random variable theta whose realization is theta (omega). Then I graphically construct the counting function of a Poisson process of constant intensity whose value is theta (omega).

I want to find a command that repeats this construction automatically to get a graph with several realizations of the count function